# C# how to correctly use dictionary in Database and code?

Tags: c#, database, dictionary

I think I got an architecture problem.

For the example purpose let's say I have a table named Dict.Country with two columns : Id and Name like below. The reason why I have such a table and not only Enum in code is because with time we want to dynamically add another values.

```
1   USA
2   POLAND
3   CHINA
```

etc.

So now is the question, how to correctly read and operate on these values? I can create class DictElement with string fields Id and Column, then read them from database and operate, but we got the problem that we have to operate on strings literals:

```
if (x.country == "POLAND")
 ...
```

which I believe is bad practice, cause one small misspelling can make us much troubles.

Is there any good practice how to work on such dictionaries from database?

Comment: What sort of thing do you have in that if statement? Can all the differences be stored in the database so rather than doing that if (and presumably a load of else ifs) you'd just do `GetStuff(x.country)` instead?

Comment: It is worth noting that noble though your goal of not having it as an enum because it might change if you need to change the code when you add new values anyway you lose a lot of the reason for putting them in the database.

Comment: use-case is to simple, if its just countrys then that is not a good example... for enum usage. So if its simple data like this then forget enum's stuff. but if its is applicable... i.e. specific logic then put in enums and have a matching table for getting descriptions in 'SQL'. if you say that you want to dynamically add new values.. without changing the code, then the usage is incorrect. i.e. adding value as code enum, means there is new logic. which means you would need to update the code anyway. Data such as country does not require adding new logic, well depending but 99 use-case.

Comment: So i would suggest you ask, does it make sense to make enums for x entity's in code because of y reason.